# Six month business visa for work and leisure?

Tags: visas, india, business-travel

I will be going to India for work for around a month, I asked my manager if I could then take some of my leave after I have finished to go travelling around India.

With a Business Visa that I have applied for, will I encounter any problems doing this?

When I applied for a Visa there was no Business/Leisure joint visa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should not have any problem roaming around India on a valid business visa. Most places in India welcome foreigners and very rarely you will be stopped and asked for valid visa. if you carry your passport and visa copies along with you at all times - you should be fine.